# Use different azure pipelines template depending on checked out branch/tag

Tags: azure-pipelines

We are now moving to Azure pipelines in our organization and we will use the template mechanism to centrally make changes to the build logic.

See our current example below.

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMddHHss).$(SourceBranchName).$(Build.SourceVersion)

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: build_resources  # id for reuse in below script code
    type: git  # use 'git' for Azure git repository
    name: build-resources  # repository name
    ref: refs/tags/1.1.2

jobs:
- template: build/azure-pipelines-template.yml@build_resources  # Template reference
  parameters:
    projectfolder: 'blabla'
```

This would always check out the specific version of the build template.

We would now like to realize the following:
When the checked-out branch is "develop" then always the newest version of the build template shall be used. But when let's say a "release" branch or even a tag is being built one fixed version of the build templates shall be used.

My idea was to use some string processing in YAML and then choose a different repository resource. But I am not sure if this is possible in YAML and whether there are better approaches that you could recommend to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested; however, have you considered using something like:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: build_resources  # id for reuse in below script code
    type: git  # use 'git' for Azure git repository
    name: build-resources  # repository name
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop') }}:
      ref: 'refs/tags/newest'
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      ref: 'refs/tags/stable'
```

I found a great example here: [ADO Pipeline - Expressions - Conditional Insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion)

Comment: This is not possible. Following error message is then appearing: A template expression is not allowed in this context.

Comment: Hi Marko,
We cannot use condition in the repo, we can use [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable) in the job, step and variable instead of resource level

Answer (score 0):

You can call different templates from a pipeline YAML depending on a condition. In this example, the stable.yml YAML will run when the run the branch test.

stable.yml

```
steps:

- script: echo "stable.yml"
```

experimental.yml

```
steps:

- script: echo "experimental.yml"
```

YAML code:

```
steps:

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop') }}:

  - template: experimental.yml

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release') }}:

  - template: stable.yml
```

Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime) for more details.